# How to change all the keys of a hash by a new set of given keys

Tags: ruby, hash

How do I change all the keys of a hash by a new set of given keys?

Is there a way to do that elegantly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ruby 2.5 has [Hash#transform_keys!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) method. Example using a map of keys

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
key_map = {a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C'}

h.transform_keys! {|k| key_map[k]}
# => {"A"=>1, "B"=>2, "C"=>3}
```

You can also use symbol#toproc shortcut with transform_keys Eg:

```
h.transform_keys! &:upcase
# => {"A"=>1, "B"=>2, "C"=>3}
```

Answer (score 79):

Assuming you have a `Hash` which maps old keys to new keys, you could do something like

```
hsh.transform_keys(&key_map.method(:[]))
```

Comment: You are the man! Your hash is totally awesome! Thanks again for this gem! :)

Comment: It also assumes you have `key_map` defined as a hash of key/value pairs where the key is the old key and the value is the new key being swapped in.

Comment: anyone could explain how the `&key_map.method(:[])` works?

Answer (score 4):

i assume you want to change the hash `keys` without changing the values:

```
hash = {
   "nr"=>"123",
   "name"=>"Herrmann Hofreiter",
   "pferd"=>"010 000 777",
   "land"=>"hight land"
}
header = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]
new_hash = header.zip(hash.values).to_h
```

Result:

```
{
   "aa"=>"123",
   "bb"=>"Herrmann Hofreiter",
   "cc"=>"010 000 777",
   "dd"=>"high land"
}
```

Comment: A moment of self promotion ☺️, but just to leave it here: if anything a bit more complex needed (like select particular keys at the same time or coerce values' types and so on), I put together a tiny lib: https://github.com/smileart/hash_remapper

Comment: You take advantage of the fact that order is preserved in hashes (since 2.0 I think) and by assumption (not given in my question) that new keys are also given in the same order as in the initial hash.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is:

```
hash = {
  'foo' => 1,
  'bar' => 2
}

new_keys = {
  'foo' => 'foozle',
  'bar' => 'barzle'
}

new_keys.values.zip(hash.values_at(*new_keys.keys)).to_h 
# => {"foozle"=>1, "barzle"=>2}
```

Breaking it down:

```
new_keys
.values # => ["foozle", "barzle"]
.zip(
  hash.values_at(*new_keys.keys) # => [1, 2]
) # => [["foozle", 1], ["barzle", 2]]
.to_h 
# => {"foozle"=>1, "barzle"=>2}
```

---

It's benchmark time...

While I like the simplicity of Jörn's answer, I'm wasn't sure it was as fast as it should be, then I saw selvamani's comment:

```
require 'fruity'

HASH = {
  'foo' => 1,
  'bar' => 2
}

NEW_KEYS = {
  'foo' => 'foozle',
  'bar' => 'barzle'
}

compare do
  mittag    { HASH.dup.map {|k, v| [NEW_KEYS[k], v] }.to_h }
  ttm       { h = HASH.dup; NEW_KEYS.values.zip(h.values_at(*NEW_KEYS.keys)).to_h }
  selvamani { h = HASH.dup; h.keys.each { |key| h[NEW_KEYS[key]] = h.delete(key)}; h }
end

# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> selvamani is faster than ttm by 39.99999999999999% ± 10.0%
# >> ttm is faster than mittag by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
```

These are running very close together speed wise, so any will do, but  39% pays off over time so consider that. A couple answers were not included because there are potential flaws where they'd return bad results.

Answer (score 2):

The exact solution would depend on the format that you have the new keys in (or if you can derive the new key from the old key.)

Assuming you have a hash `h` whose keys you want to modify and a hash `new_keys` that maps the current keys to the new keys you could do:

```
h.keys.each do |key|
  h[new_keys[key]] = h[key] # add entry for new key
  k.delete(key)             # remove old key
end
```

Comment: This will remove a value for `key` when `new_keys` accidentally happens to return `key` itself for some `key`. barbolos's answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137824 overcomes this problem.

Comment: instead of this you can use `h.keys.each { |key| h[new_keys[key]] = h.delete(key)}`

Comment: @Selvamani, see my answer, and create an answer from your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you also worry about performance, this is faster:

```
hsh.keys.each { |k| hsh[ key_map[k] ] = hsh.delete(k) if key_map[k] }
```

You don't create a new Hash and you rename only the necessary keys. That gives you better performance.

You can find more details in "[How to elegantly rename all keys in a hash in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137824/how-to-elegantly-rename-all-keys-in-a-hash-in-ruby/12534710#12534710)"

Comment: This breaks if `key_map[k]` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = { 'foo'=>1, 'bar'=>2 }
key_map = { 'foo'=>'foozle', 'bar'=>'barzle' }

h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g[key_map[k]]=v }
  #=> {"foozle"=>1, "barzle"=>2}
```

or

```
h.reduce({}) { |g,(k,v)| g.merge(key_map[k]=>v) }
  #=> {"foozle"=>1, "barzle"=>2}
```

Comment: I think calling merge for each key will be comparatively slow

Comment: @Josh, you are correct. I re-ran @theTinMan's benchmark with my two methods added and obtained the following results: "selvamani is faster than ttm by 19.99% ± 1.0%; ttm is similar to caryewo (uses `each_with_object`); caryewo is similar to mittag; mittag is faster than caryred (uses `reduce`) by 70.0% ± 10.0%".