# How do I add a prefix to each key in a hash?

Tags: ruby

I have the following keys in my hash:

```
address, postcode
```

I want to add the "shipping_" prefix to each of them so they would become:

```
shipping_address, shipping_postcode
```

instead. How can I do this?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210572/how-to-replace-a-hash-key-with-another-key) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137824/how-to-elegantly-rename-all-keys-in-a-hash-in-ruby) on how to replace the keys in a hash might help you out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
hsh1 = {'address' => "foo", 'postcode' => "bar"}
hsh2 = Hash[hsh1.map{|k,v| [k.dup.prepend("shipping_"),v]}]
p hsh2
# >> {"shipping_address"=>"foo", "shipping_postcode"=>"bar"}
```

**update**

```
hsh1 = {'address' => "foo", 'postcode' => "bar"}
hsh2 = Hash[hsh1.map{|k,v| ["shipping_#{k}",v]}]
p hsh2
# >> {"shipping_address"=>"foo", "shipping_postcode"=>"bar"}
```

Comment: Instead of `k.dup.prepend("shipping_")` let Ruby handle the `dup.prepend` by using `"shipping_#{k}"`. It's more obvious what's going on.

Answer (score 8):

In Ruby >= 2.5, you can do

```
hsh.transform_keys! {|k| 'shipping_' + k }
# => {"shipping_address"=>"foo", "shipping_postcode"=>"bar"}
```

And if you want to be fancy

```
hsh.transform_keys! &'shipping_'.method(:+)
# => {"shipping_address"=>"foo", "shipping_postcode"=>"bar"}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it destructively, this is a short way:

```
hash.keys.each{|k| hash.store("shipping_#{k}", hash.delete(k))}
```