# Ruby: Rename keys in array of hashes?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, key, rename

How do I rename the `_id` keys to `id` in an array of MongoDB documents?

So, I want to make this:

```
[{"_id"=>"1", "name"=>"Matt"}, {"_id"=>"2", "name"=>"John"}, ...]
```

into this:

```
[{"id"=>"1", "name"=>"Matt"}, {"id"=>"2", "name"=>"John"}, ...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the complete solution.

```
mongo_db['users'].find().to_a.each do |u|
  u['id'] = u.delete '_id'
end.to_json
```

Comment: This works perfectly well, however, it is really not that obvious (at a glance) what is being done, so might confuse another coder. Making this a helper method, or at least adding a comment, would make it better.

Answer (score 5):

```
ar = [{"_id"=>"1", "name"=>"Matt"}, {"_id"=>"2", "name"=>"John"}]
ar.each{|h| h.store('id',h.delete('_id'))}
ar # => [{"name"=>"Matt", "id"=>"1"}, {"name"=>"John", "id"=>"2"}]
```

If you don't want to modify the original array do as below:

```
ar = [{"_id"=>"1", "name"=>"Matt"}, {"_id"=>"2", "name"=>"John"}]
ar.map{|h| {"id"=>h['_id'], "name"=>h['name']} }
# => [{"id"=>"1", "name"=>"Matt"}, {"id"=>"2", "name"=>"John"}]
```