# Pretty, Rubified JSON keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

**What's the best way to get pretty, Rubified hash keys?**

Ie. `someKey` becomes `some_key`.

1. [Hashie::Trash](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) -- impossible without first defining each key, ie. `property :some_key, from: :someKey` -- not very pretty.
2. https://github.com/tcocca/rash -- unfortunately [breaks Hashie::Extensions::DeepFetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193313/rash-breaks-hashieextensionsdeepfetch) which I intend to use later on.
3. [Rails ActiveSupport's `underscore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509915/converting-camel-case-to-underscore-case-in-ruby) -- unclear how to apply this to my use case.

Live demo app: http://runnable.com/U-QJCIFvY2RGWL9B/pretty-json-keys

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @json_text = <<END
      ...
    END

    response = JSON.parse(@json_text)['products']

    @products = []
    response.each do |product|
      @products << product['salePrice']

      # Seeking the best way to make this say:

      # @products << product['sale_price']
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  In Rails console, `"fooBar".underscore` works fine for me.

Comment: Sure, but how do I apply it to my hashes so I can parse them using their new names?

Comment: This question might be helpful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210572/how-to-replace-a-hash-key-with-another-key

Comment: Use your own hash class or patch the existing one, similar to how the indifferent class works.

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry what do you mean exactly?

Comment: What @DaveNewton means is that Rails already has [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess) where you can access keys using either a string or symbol. Your use case is similar.

Comment: @MarkThomas still a bit confused, but would you say something like that would be better than the current accepted answer?

Comment: Not necessarily better, just different.

Comment: Any chance either of you guys could cook up an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can always translate to a new hash:

```
def self.prettify(x)
  x.is_a?(Hash) ? Hash[ x.map{|k,v| [k.underscore, prettify(v)]} ] :
  x.is_a?(Array) ? x.map{|v| prettify(v) } : x
end

pretty_json_hash = prettify(JSON.parse(@json_text))
```

NB: Success with Rails will be hard to come by if you can't write code at this level.

Comment: I am unable to make it work. In `main_controller.rb`, `salePrice` works but `sale_price` doesn't: http://runnable.com/U-QJCIFvY2RGWL9B/pretty-json-keys

Comment: @MarkBoulder The link isn't doing anything on my end. You're going to have to post the code that isn't working, including the JSON that's being parsed. Given a hash of hashes, `prettify` above certainly traverses it and transforms all the keys. Maybe you have a list in your JSON? The code above does not deal with nestings that include lists.

Comment: Are you unable to access Runnable? If you can access it, you just have to click the `Run` button to launch the app. `main_controller.rb` should be easily accessible in the files and folder tree.

Comment: If not, please see https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/1928331dabab186dfa6c.

Comment: @MarkBoulder Clicking yields nothing.  I'm at work where we're wired to IE9.  Maybe that's it.

Comment: @MarkBoulder Okay now I see it.  Exactly as I asked above the `products` field and several others are wrapped in arrays.  I'll add code to handle that case.

Comment: Super awesome man! Thank you so much! The live app now works perfectly.

Comment: Real quick, could it be written like this? https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/e0cbc5ba3584c722596f

Comment: @MarkBoulder No.  You need a final `else` clause that contains only `x`.

Comment: Updated gist. But I can see why yours is prettier now.