# Rails: RuntimeError: can't add a new key into hash during iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, thread-safety, puma

In my rails 4.2.7 app running on puma deployed on Heroku in clustered mode with 2 workers and 8 threads, I get the following error in Rollbar. My Memory usage is also high, sometimes crossing limit for 1x dyno.

```
RuntimeError: can't add a new key into hash during iteration
File "/app/app/views/shared/_navigation.html.haml" line 4 in block in _app_views_shared__navigation_html_haml___3017256416239853871_69904621111460
+ 8 non-project frames
```

Here is code block mentioning the lines

```
= link_to root_url, class: 'logo', rel: 'home', itemprop: 'logo', itemscope: true, itemtype: 'https://schema.org/ImageObject' do
  = image_tag 'logo', alt: '9curry', title: 'AppName', itemprop: 'url'
  %meta{ content: '264', itemprop: 'width' }
  %meta{ content: '73', itemprop: 'height' }
%meta{ content: root_url, itemprop: 'url' }
%meta{ content: 'AppName', itemprop: 'name' }
```

And similar error is thrown for following block of code

```
.play-store
  = link_to '#', rel: 'nofollow' do
    = image_tag 'google-play-badge', width: 200
```

Comment: Is your memory used over the computer max?

Comment: why you have indented two `meta` tags within image tag?

Comment: @SachinSingh Edited code now, pasting changed it, corrected the indentation now

Comment: @Tsao Sometimes it's above max, and it starts using swap.

Comment: @StarWars Could you fix it ?

Comment: I had the same issue. Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52387808/586195 is my workaround