# ruby - How to replace a hash key/value with another key/value

Tags: ruby

I have a hash

```
  hash = {"some_wierd_name"=>"cheesemonster", .....}
```

and I want this hash as

```
  hash = {"preferred_name"=>"cheesemonster", ......}
```

What is the shortest way to do that?

Comment: Hashes are ordered, do you need to preserve that order?

Comment: @mu makes a good point. Maybe you want `{ "preferred_name" => hash.delete("some_weird_name") }.merge hash`.

Answer (score 6):

```
hash["preferred_name"] = hash.delete("some_wierd_name")
```

Hash keys are *frozen* strings, they can’t be modified inplace, and the frozen state can’t be removed from an object. That said, tricks with `prepend` and `replace` won’t work resulting in:

```
RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
```

Therefore, there is the only possibility: to remove the old value and insert the new one.

Comment: If packaged in a method, `hash` is needed as the last line.

Answer (score 3):

```
hash = {"some_wierd_name"=>"cheesemonster"}

hash["preferred_name"] = hash["some_wierd_name"]
hash.delete("some_wierd_name")
```

Comment: Just a note that (since `hash.delete("some_wierd_name")
 => "cheesemonster"`) if this is packaged in a method, `hash` is needed as the last line.

Answer (score 1):

- If we are looking to replace the key/value both, can be done easily by using rails except method. You can also use the delete method but one key/value pair at a time but be using except can remove 2 or more key/value pair.

  ```
  hash = {a: 1, b:2, c: 3}
  hash.except!(:a)[:d] = 4 
  and it is similar to these two following line
  hash.except!(:a) 
  hash[:d] = 4
  hash = {:b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}
  ```
- Changing only key of the hash, value remains same. One can also use the reject. reject and delete_if are same.

  ```
  hash[:e] = hash.delete(:d) 
       or 
  temp = hash[d]
  hash.delete_if{|key| key ==:d }
  hash[:e] = temp
  hash = {:b=>2, :c=>3, :e=>4}
  ```
- Changing only value, the key remains same. This one pretty easy.

  ```
  hash[:e] = 5
  ```

References :

- [delete](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/delete)
- [except](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except)
- [hash](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Hash.html)

Answer (score 0):

for a single key, use `delete`

```
hash["preferred_name"] = hash.delete("some_wierd_name")
```

If you need to update all the keys, i suggest using inject

```
new_hash = hash.inject({}) do |returned_hash, (key, value)|
  returned_hash[key] = value.upcase;
  returned_hash
end
```

Comment: Self-answers are not a problem and are not frowned upon in general. Also, the answer is correct and pretty complete, nothing to worry about.

Comment: As a tiny addition, instead of `inject`, you can also use [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-each_with_object) to get rid of the second line in the block.

Comment: @HolgerJust, I would agree with you if it were a challenging question, but this one is not. I have seen this technique for renaming a key many, many times on SO.

Comment: @HolgerJust “to get rid of the second line in the block”—`each_with_object` is **not about getting rid of last line**, it’s about mutating the same object instead of producing new one on each iteration.

Comment: Why `value.upcase`? And why not use `each_with_object({})` when you're not really injecting? Or use `h.merge(k => v.upcase)` as the block if you are injecting. And your `inject` version isn't renaming any keys, it is modifying the values.

Comment: @mudasobwa In this case, it is. With the `inject` idiom used here, there is already the same object returned each time. When using `each_with _object` (or even `each.with_object)`, it just becomes more explicit and more concise to write.

Comment: @HolgerJust I have no problems with self answers, but the timestamps between the answer and question were less than a minute apart, which leads me to believe that the question that the answer wasn't reasoned about from comments here, but just a shameless point-grab.

Comment: I also agree `each_with_object` is the optimal approach here `new_hash = hash.each_with_object({}) {|(k, v), hash| hash[k] = v.upcase }`

Comment: @Sean, I think "shameless point-grab" is rather harsh. Some very experienced Rubiests here regularly post questions and then immediately post an answer. In effect, they are saying, "This the best I could come up with. Is there a better way?" Typically it is a challenging problem they've encountered on the job. It has nothing to do with rep.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're exactly right, and i also like to ask/answer questions when a similar search returns articles/answers that are not answering the exact question in title.

Comment: @Sean I originally found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210572/how-to-replace-a-hash-key-with-another-key which looks to be more about regex than ruby hash particulars. /shrug i'm fine with downvotes :) not here for the points.

Comment: Answering your own question is also a way to get around the requirement that questions with working code are not suitable for SO (and should be moved to Code Review). :-)