# Replace double quote with colon before hash rocket

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the follow hash:

```
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('567ccbd747824a621d8b4567'), "response"=>{"version"=>"1.1", "statusCode"=>302, "headers"=>{"content-type"=>[""], "content-length"=>[""], "host"=>["54.223.52.194:9011"], "connection"=>["keep-alive"], "cache-control"=>["max-age=0"], "accept"=>["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"], "upgrade-insecure-requests"=>["1"], "user-agent"=>["Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36"], "accept-encoding"=>["gzip, deflate, sdch"], .......}
```

I want to replace the double quote with colon. The expected output is:

```
{:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('567ccbd747824a621d8b4567'), :response=>{:version=>"1.1",.....}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Not quite duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4045194/2988

Answer (score 3):

Build a new Hash, with symbolic keys:

```
def symbolize_keys(o)
   case o
   when Hash
     Hash[o.map { |k, v| [k.to_sym, symbolize_keys(v)] }]
   when Array
     o.map { |e| symbolize_keys(e) }
   else
     o
   end
end
```

(Assuming you meant "colon" and not "comma")

Comment: Thanks  ! u save my day

Answer (score 2):

Just map all the keys to `Symbol`s:

```
hsh.transform_keys(&:to_sym)
```